# JPA with Spring Embebed Database not records found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

Starting from a program that was connected to a mysql database, using spring, JPA and JDBC, I am trying to configure that application to use the H2 database in embedded mode.

With MYSQL everything works fine, but with H2 not.

I can not get H2 to return any records, although the records are there so if I do the same query through JDBC, if I see them.

The configuration that I have is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("yages.yagesserver")
@EnableTransactionManagement

public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) 
                .setName("yagesh2")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("db/sql/create-db.sql")
                .addScript("db/sql/insert-data.sql")
                .generateUniqueName(false)     
                .build();
        return db;
    }
    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
     }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());              

        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"yages.yagesserver", "yages.yagesserver.dao"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("yages-server");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em;
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }    


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

So if I write this code:

```
String s="SELECT  cal_ano,cal_mes,cal_fecini,cal_fecfin from calendario where cal_ano=? and cal_mes = ?";

        List<Calendario> cal =
                jdbc.query(s,    new Object[] { ano,mes}, 
                 (rs, rowNum) -> new Calendario(
                            rs.getInt("cal_ano"),rs.getInt("cal_mes"),rs.getDate("cal_fecini"),rs.getDate("cal_fecfin"))
                        );    
        System.out.println("getDatosSemana. Size "+cal.size()+ "Fecha Inicio: "+cal.get(0).getFechaInicio());

        Optional<Calendario> calOpc = calendarioRepositorio.getCalendario(new CalendarioKey(ano - 1, mes));
        System.out.println("getDatosSemana. Optional is present: "+calOpc.isPresent());
```

When I use JDBC I see that in the calendar table if the record exists, but when using JPA, it does not seem to find anything.

This is the output in my console:

```
getDatosSemana. Size 1Fecha Inicio: 2018-01-28
Hibernate: select calendario0_.cal_ano as cal_ano1_0_0_, calendario0_.cal_mes as cal_mes2_0_0_, calendario0_.cal_fecfin as cal_fecf3_0_0_, calendario0_.cal_fecini as cal_feci4_0_0_ from calendario calendario0_ where calendario0_.cal_ano=? and calendario0_.cal_mes=?
getDatosSemana. Optional is present: false
```

Of course I have the DAO classes and my repository that extends from a CrudRepository.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: could you add your calendarioRepositorio.getCalendario code? Are you using Spring data jpa? If you want to use h2 LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is not  a must. You only have to define depency in your pom and Spring boot will auto configure your entity manager.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found the error... I feel the discomfort. Look the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I have found the error.
It was a failure foolishness. I called the JPA function with the parameters of year and month reversed.
Sometimes you do not see the obvious.